# Order of Joins SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I ran across a curious issue earlier today while writing a multiple JOIN query in MS SQL Server and I am hoping somebody may be able to help me to understand better.  Typically I like to join tables in the order I pull from them in the SELECT statement (just seems easier and cleaner to me).  The below statement works only because it is not in order of the SELECT statement and I don't know why.  If I re-wrote it to join VW_ORDER_HEADER --> VW_ORDER_ITEM --> VW_PO_ITEM in that order it returns no results.  I only discovered this works after designing it in Access and looking at the resulting SQL.  I am not new to SQL Server but at first and second glance I can't see why the order of the join would make a difference... Thanks in advance

```
 SELECT O.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
           O.BILL_TO, 
           O.SHIP_TO, 
           O.SOLD_TO, 
           O.ORDER_DATE,
           O.REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE, 
           O.VALID_TO_DATE, 
           O.OPEN_QUANTITY,
           OI.MATERIAL, 
           PI.PO_NUMBER



    FROM   VW_PO_ITEM PI 

    JOIN   VW_ORDER_ITEM OI ON PI.MATERIAL = OI.MATERIAL 

    JOIN   VW_ORDER_HEADER O ON OI.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = O.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER

    WHERE  OI.MATERIAL = 'BA7948' 

    AND    O.OPEN_QUANTITY > 0 

    AND    O.VALID_TO_DATE >= GETDATE()

    ORDER BY O.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
             O.ORDER_DATE ASC;
```

Comment: can you add the other query as well ? the columns you join in sql are really important. if the columns are not changed then your result should also not change.

Comment: The order of joins with `inner join` doesn't make a difference.  Something else is going on.

Comment: can  you show us the query that does not work ?

Comment: alright all...this one may have been due to user error lol - I just re-created the other way and same result....sorry to waste your time and thank you for taking a look, sometimes on those long days you gotta go for a walk.  One related question - my company LOVES Access for reporting and I hate it as I learned on SQL Server/Oracle - why does Access write queries in that order?  Is it more efficient?